# Create View with STUFF function using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-view

I have a create view and I am using the `STUFF` function. I have it working where it takes one field from one table and stuffs it. However those values are int's and they have corresponding descriptions in another table. So I would have **"4, 5"** in my stuff field and I would like it to be **"this is #4 description, this is #5 description"**. My create view and STUFF function is the following and the tables are linked by `ConditionsReasonsID` however I need the `RequestedBurnsID` for the original stuff and to be used in my create view.

```
CREATE VIEW [AQB_OB].[GISREQUESTEDBURNS] 
AS

with conditions as 
(SELECT DISTINCT BD.[RequestedBurnsID]
,[ConditionsReasonsID] = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[ConditionsReasonsID]) 
FROM [AQB_OB].[BurnDecisions] WHERE [RequestedBurnsID]= BD.[RequestedBurnsID] 
ORDER BY [RequestedBurnsID] ASC
FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1 , 1, '') FROM
[AQB_OB].[BurnDecisions] BD)

SELECT RB.[RequestedBurnsID] AS REQUESTEDBURNID
  ,BUY.[BurnYear] AS BURNYEAR
  ,CY.[CurrentYear] AS CURRENTYEAR
  ,RB.[BurnSitesID] AS BURNSITESID
  ,[BurnerID] AS BURNERID
  ,[BurnStartDate] AS BURNSTARTDATE
  ,[BurnEndDate] AS BURNENDDATE
  ,[BurnDecision] AS BURNDECISION
  ,RB.[Comment] AS COMMENT
  ,CC.ConditionsReasonsID AS CONDITIONS

  FROM [AQB_MON].[AQB_OB].[RequestedBurns] RB
 inner join AQB_MON.[AQB_OB].[BurnSites] BS on RB.BurnSitesID = BS.BurnSitesID
full outer join  conditions CC on CC.RequestedBurnsID = RB.RequestedBurnsID 
INNER JOIN [AQB_OB].[ConditionsReasons] CR ON CR.ConditionsReasonsID = CC.ConditionsReasonsID
GO
```

Update - My table structure for the two table - BurnDecision and ConditionsReasons. I need the `SELECT DISTINCT` as it ties to RequestedBurnes as that is the table the view is created around.

[image]

Update - Result with original sql statement. I would like the integers in the Conditions column to be string descriptions from the ConditionsReasons table.

[image]

Comment: `',this is #' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[ConditionsReasonsID]) + ' description'` ?

Comment: I'm sorry I stated that wrong. the other table has the descriptions for 4 and 5 which could be "cannot burn after 4pm" or "can only burn between 11am and 4pm"

Comment: I am unsure why you cannot modify your stuff statement to achieve that, or add another one to achieve it. I don't know your table structure but that seems simple enough.

Comment: I updated my question with my table structure as I am unsure how to modify the stuff statement

Comment: can you show an example of the actual output and the desired one?

Comment: I updated my question again to show the result of what the original view would result. The `STUFF` fills the last column CONDITIONS. I would like those integers to be the string Description from another table.

Comment: You could change the stuff to be like `select ',' + C.[Description] from [AQB_OB].[BurnDecisions] B JOIN [AQB_OB].[ConditionReasons] C ON C.[ConditionReasonsID] = B.[ConditionReasonsID] WHERE B.[RequestedBurnsID] = BD.[RequestedBurnsID]...`, which _should_ work, but I imagine the entire query could be simplified in a much better way.

Comment: when I create the `STUFF` above it gives a row for each condition instead of stuffing them.

Comment: ZLK's answer worked when I used an `inner join` on the second table. Thank-you